# Ubuntu Server 12.04: Network is unreachable

Tags: linux, сервер, сеть, ubuntu

Поставил сервер, обновил и - долгая загрузка с сообщениями:    Waiting for network configuration    ...    Waiting 60 seconds more for network configuration    ...    Booting system without full network configurationВ итоге система грузится без сети. Раздел Network системных настроек:    The system network services are not compatible with this version.Результат попытки пинговать ip 8.8.8.8     Network is unreachable.На многих форумах вижу [одно и то же решение, в котором я не вижу никакой логики](https://askubuntu.com/questions/146948/internet-on-ubuntu-12-04-stopped-to-work-after-installing-updates-from-the-updat): а) при отвалившемся интернете предлагают скачать (!) предыдущую версию пакета "network-manager", б) который - если его установить - доработает ровно до следующего обновления.Как реанимировать сеть? Крайне хотелось бы вариант без даунгрейда и дополнительных закачек.

Comment: А зачем на сервере (!) network-manager ?

Comment: Есть возможность поставить десктопный GUI поверх сервера - вот и поставил.

Comment: Спасибо @pyatak за наводку. Проблема была в накатанном поверх сервера Ubuntu Desktop'е. Теперь понятно, что так делать не надо - чистая консоль без всякого GUI. Переустановил, обновил - все работает.

Comment: @DenisKhvorostin, пожалуйста, оформите решение в качестве ответа, чтобы Вы могли получить заслуженную репутацию. Если Вы не успеете сделать это до 09.08, я оформлю ответ в качестве общего (за него не начисляется репутация) - это необходимо для улучшения структуризации содержимого сайта.

Comment: @soon, оформите ответ?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, готово

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*<sub>Ответ перенесен из комментариев к вопросу:</sub>*

---

Спасибо @pyatak за наводку:

> А зачем на сервере (!) network-manager ?

Проблема была в накатанном поверх сервера Ubuntu Desktop'е. Теперь понятно, что так делать не надо - чистая консоль без всякого GUI.

Переустановил, обновил - все работает.